# Adding active class to navigation menu failed with deeper url

Tags: jquery, url, menu

I want to add the class "active" on item menu when the relative page is on.

the menu is very simple:

```
<ul id="main-menu">
<li class="blue">
<a href="http://localhost/maxinventions/">Home</a>
</li>
<li class="orange">
<a href="http://localhost/maxinventions/client">Clients</a>
</li>
<li class="puprle">
<a class="active" href="http://localhost/maxinventions/work">Work</a>
</li>
<li class="yellow">
<a href="http://localhost/maxinventions/about">About Us</a>
</li>
<li class="green">
<a href="http://localhost/maxinventions/contact">Contact Us</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

i have been able to add active class to the menu, but the problem is when i access deeper url the script cannot work. for example if i access http://my-site.com/work/web-architecture-and-development the active class is gone.

here is my script

```
$(function(){

var url = window.location.pathname, 
    urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/,'') + "$"); 
    $('#main-menu a').each(function(){
        // and test its normalized href against the url pathname regexp
        if(urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/,''))){
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

any solution?

Comment: When you follow a link, the entire page is reloaded.

Comment: so how should i do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect. The deep page isn't listed in the navigation menu, why should it have the active class?

Comment: it should, because it marks where you are, i want it if the i access my-site.com/work/aaaa my-site.com/work/bbbb my-site.com/work/cccc the class is still active so the navigation menu is still highlighted. how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like your regular expression is not matching. With your examples:

For the url http://my-site.com/work/aaaa your `window.location.pathname` is "/work/aaaa".

This: `urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/,'') + "$");` results in `/\/work\/aaaa$/`, in other words strings that end with /work/aaaa.

Your nav href is going to be `http://my-site.com/work`. This doesn't match your urlRegExp; the href does not end with /work/aaaa.

What I think you want is something along these lines:

```
var url = window.location.pathname,
    myDomain = 'http://my-site.com/';

$('#main-menu a').each(function(){
    if(url.indexOf(this.href.replace(myDomain,'')) > 0){
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Comment: ah thank you but it always highlighted the home navigation so i edited your code, change >= to > works like a charm